# Sound Recorder Widget doesnt stop recording

Tags: android

My application involves plenty of sound recording, so I made a widget to be able to record from the Home screen.
I have a class Recorder.java where I deal with all the MediaRecorder calls.
When recording from the activity, everything works fine. When recording from widget, it records, but doesn't stop recording when it should.

Here is the code I use to stop from the activity:

```
//r is an instance of Recorder.java
if (r.getState() == Recorder.RECORDING) {
                r.stopRecording();

            }
```

When the recording button in the widget is pressed, it starts a service, that checks the recorder state. If r is recording then it stops, if it isn't then it starts recording. This checks works because when its recording and I press it I get a Toast that should appear *after* it stopped recording, but it never stops recording.
On the service I also use `r.stopRecording();`

Any ideas what might be wrong in my code?

Comment: any luck with stopping recording? I have the same situation.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I never got it to work, so my implementation was rather dirty, killing the service and hoping that the OS would handle it correctly.

Comment: ok, nevermind, if I get the answer ill post it on SO very soon:)

Answer (score 0):

please Try to use `prepare()` after `Stop()` called and at last relase() the `MediaRecorder` Object

Comment: stopRecording() method basically has recorder.stop() and recorder.release() and recorder = null;                               Whats weird is that it does works when I call it from the activity, but not from the Widget/service.

Comment: please post the full code.. that I Can understand the things. Thanks