# Can't stop recording?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop Recording and Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601005/stop-recording-and-context)

I can't understand what's wrong ?!!! 
When the phone rings then recording starts.
But when the call ends I get NullPointerException, because MediRecorder is null, but recording is still going until I shut the window with an error. 
My problem the same as this [Sound Recorder Widget doesnt stop recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868966/sound-recorder-widget-doesnt-stop-recording)

```
public class Call extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder;    
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {           
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(null == bundle) return;
        String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {          
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/Record.3gp";);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            try {mRecorder.prepare();} 
            catch (IOException e){}
            mRecorder.start();

            // if I stop recording here, then everything is fine
            /* 
               try 
                    {Thread.sleep(300000);} 
               catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {e.printStackTrace();}
               mRecorder.stop();
               mRecorder.release();
               mRecorder = null;    
            */

        }

        if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
        {
            if(mRecorder != null)  // But this always false. if I remove this condition -
            {
                 mRecorder.stop(); // - then here NullPointerException
                 mRecorder.release();
                 mRecorder = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
10-01 07:13:28.054: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver xxx.xxx.xxx.Call: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2646)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3100(ActivityThread.java:119)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at xxx.xxx.xxx.Call.onReceive(Call.java:49)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2637)
10-01 07:13:29.134: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(553):     ... 10 more
10-01 07:13:33.184: ERROR/audio_input(31): unsupported parameter: x-pvmf/media-input-node/cap-config-interface;valtype=key_specific_value
10-01 07:13:33.184: ERROR/audio_input(31): VerifyAndSetParameter failed
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a new instance of a MediaRecorder object in your "if phone is ringing" statement using the same name as your class MediaRecorder object, which is then lost as soon as you leave the scope of that if statement. Simply remove the `MediaRecorder` declaration in front of the line `MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did as you and slayton said, but it not helped

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are instantiating a new `MediaRecorder` inside your `if` statement which is masking the `MediaRecorder mRecorder` class member. So Change:

```
  if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {          
            MediaRecorder mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        .....
        }
```

to this:

```
  if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
        {          
           mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        .....
        }
```